# How do I make a set of thumbnails sized to fit a row for using wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress, nested-loops

I want rows of images that are always 900px wide when combined.

If its 1 image the height is varriable and width is 900px
2 images one might be 300px wide and the other 600px wide.

Here is my attempt so far.

```
    <?php
        $maxHeight = 400;//maximum height of a thumb
        $offset = 0;//start on recent post
        $maxRowWidth = 900;//maximum width of a row
        $stopId=20;//max of 20 posts 
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 9999, $maxHeight );
        $rowWidth=0;//initial row width
        $column = 0;    

        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $tn_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
                $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $tn_id, array(9999,$maxHeight) );
                $width = $img[1];//holds the default image width given max height
                $height = $img[2];//not used yet
                $column = $column+1;
                $rowWidth = $rowWidth+$width;
                if ($rowWidth > $maxRowWidth){
                    $aspectRatio = $rowWidth / $maxHeight;
                    $height= $maxRowWidth / $aspectRatio;
                    //I get an error here when I nest this loop wordpress doesn't like this
                    $query = 'showposts='.$column.'&offset='.$offset;

                    query_posts('$query');
                    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $tn_id, array(9999,$height) );
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                                                    }
                        endwhile; else:
                    endif;
                    //wp_reset_postdata();  //commented out because I don't know if I need it
                    $offset = $offset+1;
                    $column = 0;
                    $rowWidth = 0;
                }
            }
        endwhile; else:
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you created all the required image sizes by adding them with `add_image_size()` in your `functions.php` file?

Comment: When I ran it earlier it I didn't need to.  I could just change the thumbnail size for this instance

Comment: So what is your script currently doing and what isn't it doing?

Comment: from the load time it seems like I have an infinite loop (I uncommented the wp_reset_postdata();)  I just confirmed its an infinite loop if wp_reset_postdata() is commented or not. via view source

Comment: I want it to make my thumbnails rows of however many will fit  but rather than just wrapping and leaving the last image uneven I want the images squared off.